# PHP Form Writing No values to db from array in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a form that collects info from an input array named question3 then i post it to the process php page and it writes nothing to the comments field in the database OR depending on explode function i tried it writes "Array" into all the comment fields.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($_POST['question3'] as $key3 => $ans3) {
        $write = (explode(" ",$_POST['question3']));
        echo "</BR>";
        mysql_query("UPDATE trn SET comments = '$write' WHERE id = '$key3'");
        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM trn WHERE id = '$key3'";
            $res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
            while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
                $userid           = $row1['usr_id'];
                $certificate_name = $row1['certificate_name'];
                $comment = $row1['comments']; 
            } //$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)
            if ($comment == NULL) {
                echo "Successfully updated <font color=blue>$certificate_name</font> to comments = <font color=green>y</font>";
            } else {
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE id = '$userid'";
                $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
                    $fn = $row2['firstname'];
                    $ln = $row2['lastname'];
                } //$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)
                echo "Successfully updated <font color=blue>$fn $ln</font> to comments = <font color=green>y</font>";
            }
        } //mysql_affected_rows() == 1
    } //$_POST['question'] as $key => $ans
```

This is what displays from var_dump:

```
array(4) {
    [743]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(5) "Mercy" 
    } 
    [748]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(6) "Anelie" 
    } 
    [749]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(6) "Bealah" 
    } 
    [750]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "Theo" 
    } 
}
```

These values are obtained from the previous form page which posts.
 it's an intranet site no outside links so not worried about hacks.

This is the section of the form that i'm trying to input.

```
    $sql7 = "SELECT * FROM trn WHERE course_id = '$sel_course_id' AND date_1 = '$sel_date_1' and date_2 = '$sel_date_2'";
    $res6 = mysql_query($sql7);
    while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res6)) {
        $rowid6             = $row6['id'];
        $uid5               = $row6['usr_id'];
        $certificate_name5  = $row6['certificate_name'];
        $certificate_issued5 = $row6['certificate_issued'];
        $comm7 = $row6['comments'];
        if ($uid5 == 'x') {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            $checked7 = "";
            if ($comm7 == '') {
$checked7 = "$comm7";
            } else {
                $checked7 = "$comm7";
}
            echo "<input name='question3[$rowid6][]' type='text' style='width: 675px; height: 30px;' type='text' maxlength='160' $checked7 value='$comm7' />$certificate_name5" . " - Not registered on users table";
            echo "</td>";
        } else {
            $sql8 = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs WHERE id = '$uid5'";
            $res7 = mysql_query($sql8);
            while ($row7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res7)) {
                $fn6 = $row7['firstname'];
                $ln6 = $row7['lastname'];
                $com7 = $row7['comments'];
            } 
            $checked8 = "$comm7";
            if ($comm7 == '') {
$checked8 = "$comm7";
            } else {
                $checked8 = "$comm7";
}
            echo "              <tr>";
            echo "                  <td>";
            echo "<input name='question3[$rowid6][]' type='text' style='width: 675px; height: 30px;' type='text' maxlength='160' $checked8 value='$comm7'/>$fn6 $ln6";
            echo "</td>";
        } 
    } 
    echo "              </tr>";
    echo "          </table>";
    echo "          </td>";
    echo "      </tr>";
    echo "      <tr>";
    echo "          <td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "          <td><input name='Submit1' type='submit' value='submit'></td>";
    echo "      </tr>";
    echo "  </table>";
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Hm, are you sure, `$_POST['question3']` is really an array? How are the input fields in your html named exactyl? Also try `var_dump($_POST['question3']);`

Comment: You have some *HUGE* SQL injection vulnerabilities there. If this code were to go live you'd be hacked the next day. Anyway, please post the output of `print_r($_POST['question3']);` (or var_dump as MiDo asked for).

Comment: if `$_POST['question3']` is an array, why do you need this: `$write = ( explode(" ",$_POST['question3']) );`?

Comment: make sure that what you're looping through is really an array. Be it a live site or an intranet site you must always be wary of security vulnerabilities. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: your code never checks for MySQL errors.

Comment: and as @Kyokasuigetsu and Ariel have said you need to pay attention on possible SQL hacks even in intranet. Are you sure that there isn't any "bad person" connected to your intranet?

Comment: Thanks again for all the advice about the security but kinda doesnt answer my question.

Comment: and what about my frst comment?

Comment: This is what displays from var_dump on question 3 so yea:

array(4) {
    [743]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(5) "Mercy" 
    } 
    [748]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(6) "Anelie" 
    } 
    [749]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(6) "Bealah" 
    } 
    [750]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(4) "Theo" 
    } 
}